# Saving a list as a csv

Tags: r

I have a list user_complete with 2 data frames (with characters) that I want to write to a CSV. How can I do this?

```
followers <- list()
user_complete <- list()


for (i in 1:length(names)){
user <- get_followers(names[i], n = 50)
user$University <- names[i]


user_info <- lookup_users(user$user_id)

 user_info$University <- names[i]

user_info <- subset(user_info, select=c("location", "University",        "screen_name"))

user_complete[[i]] <- user_info

}


 write.csv(user_complete, file = "twitterFollowers.csv")
```

Comment: Use `lapply` or `purrr::map` to do that

Comment: how should I change the code to reflect that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26707724/writing-multiple-data-frames-into-csv-files-using-r

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209512/write-list-of-data-frames-to-separate-csv-files-with-lapply