# How to write.csv a few dataframes based on list through a loop in a specific directory using R?

Tags: r, list, csv, for-loop

I have 5 data frames

```
 df1,df2,df3,rf1,rf2
```

I wrote a script that made a list off of specific df's

```
df_list <- names(do.call("list", mget(grep("df", ls(), value=T))))
```

df_list generated these dataframes

```
df_list<-c(df1,df2,df3)
```

what i would like to do is a for loop where i run through the specific dataframes from the list and write out a csv based on their names as df's into a directory i created.

```
directory<-"C://User//Project//"
```

Comment: You mean file names should be df1, df2, df3?

Comment: I actually use data frames more appropriate as filenames  so yes.

Comment: I found the answer from this source #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26707724/writing-multiple-data-frames-into-csv-files-using-r

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing multiple data frames into .csv files using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26707724/writing-multiple-data-frames-into-csv-files-using-r)